# Dynamically call a function by overriding the typecast

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++03

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
  void who()
  {
    cout << "I am " << _name << endl;
  }

protected:
  std::string _name;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
  A()
  {
    _name = "A class";
  }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
  B()
  {
    _name = "B class";
  }
};

class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper(Base *i):_data(i)
  {
  }

  operator A()
  {
      A a;
  //  dynamic_cast<A*>(_data);
      return a;
  }

  operator B()
  {
      B a;
   // dynamic_cast<B*>(_data);
      return a;
  }
private:
  Base* _data;
};

void madeForClass(A iObject)
{
  cout << "call madeForClass A";
}

void madeForClass(B iObject)
{
  cout << "call madeForClass B";
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  Base* b = &a;

  madeForClass(Wrapper(b));

  return 0;
}
```

when I execute this, I get error from compile saying:
e**rror: call of overloaded 'madeForClass(Wrapper)' is ambiguous** 
I understand that it cannot deduce right function even though i have overloaded the typecast. But, How can I achieve such dynamism?

For more info, I somehow want to use the dynamic_cast in the overloading function or somewhere in such a way that based on the outcome of cast it should choose the corresponding madeForClass function.

For the given example, the cast will fail for 'B' hence should call madeForClass(A i);

Comment: I think that you can't. You give the compiler no reason to pick A vs. B - they are both equally likely. A human, looking at your code as provided, could not decide on A vs. B - there is simply no information.

Comment: Visitor might help.

Comment: This sounds like it might call for a template: `template <class T> class Wrapper { public: operator T() { return T(); } };`, then use `Wrapper<A>` or `Wrapper<B>` as appropriate..

Comment: What do you *want* it to deduce?

Comment: @n.m. Infact, I have not put the entire code, If you see I have dynamic_cast commented. Infact, going with the flow, Since I pass an object of type A, the dynamic_cast would fail for B but pass for A hence it should call madeForClass(A inp). This is what I am looking for but I am not finding a way to achieve.

Comment: @user3801185 - `Base` has no virtual functions, so `dynamic_cast` won't do anything useful.

Comment: But `dynamic_cast` is done at run-time, which means that both conversions operator functions actually needs to be called at run-time, and C++ doesn't work that way. The *compiler* needs to know what function to call, at the time of compilation.

Comment: Your commented out code is invalid, and it is unclear what you intend it to do. But whatever it is, a body of a function cannot influence a compiler decision in another function.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you may do

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(Base *i) : _data(i) {}

    template <typename F>
    auto Apply(F f)
    {
        if (auto a = dynamic_cast<A*>(_data)) {
            f(*a);
        } else if (auto b = dynamic_cast<B*>(_data)){
            f(*b);
        }
    }

private:
  Base* _data;
};
```

And then

```
Wrapper(base).Apply([](const auto& e){ madeForClass(e); });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/634ce543b7287048)

or use Visitor instead of manual `dynamic_cast`